# Handling Server side exceptions on Android

Tags: java, php, android

I have an android application that connects to a php webserver to fetch and set data into a database.

When connecting to my database from the webserver, if the connection cannot be established the webserver expectedly crashes. My question is what is the correct way to catch an error in php and then let the android application know that something has gone wrong.

PHP sql connect:

```
$this->dbConn = mysqli_connect ( $this->host, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass );
if (! $this->dbConn) {
    trigger_error ( 'could not connect to server' );
}
mysqli_set_charset ( $this->dbConn, "utf8" );
```

Android retrieval

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ConnectionInfo.IMAGE_RETRIEVE,
            response -> {
                Log.d("VolleyResponse",response);
                // Error needs to be caught before it can be processed
                byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(response, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
            }, error -> {
        Log.d("VolleyResponse","Error fetching image: " + error);
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("img", "");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: In the IF return a bad status like `json_encode(['status' => false, 'msg' => 'cannot connect']);` and then check for the status in the java code

Comment: Should the connect be wrapped inside a try catch so that the error doesn't show? For example, how the code is right now with the IF statement, an error is still thrown from the mysqli_connect function

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add this to your code [get error from volley](https://gist.github.com/stevandoh/6c22582252d31fc8ab47996b766c7577)

Comment: Link only answers are not encouraged on SO. At least put enough description in your answer so that it is useful to someone reading it

Comment: Sorry I meant handling a SQL error inside php and passing it to android so that the user knows that the SQL is not connected. Not actually handling a network error between the webserver and android